# Apache Spark StringIndexer applies non-existent labels (Unseen label Exception)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, classification, random-forest

I am trying to do a Random Forest Classification using PySpark 2.3.0. My dataset contains three columns which are strings so I am using the StringIndexer to convert them to numbers. Unfortuantely during the evaluation the Indexer suddenly finds labels which are not existing anywhere in the dataset.

Here is an extract of my dataset (the last column is the label 0/1):

```
Year,Month,DayofMonth,DayOfWeek,DepTime,UniqueCarrier,Origin,Dest,Distance,DepDelay15Min
2004,1,12,1,623,UA,ORD,CLT,599,0
2004,1,13,2,621,UA,ORD,CLT,599,0
2004,1,14,3,633,UA,ORD,CLT,599,0
```

Here is my script:

```
CSV_PATH = "data/mllib/2004_10000_small.csv"
APP_NAME = "Random Forest Example"
SPARK_URL = "local[*]"
RANDOM_SEED = 13579
TRAINING_DATA_RATIO = 0.7
RF_NUM_TREES = 10
RF_MAX_DEPTH = 30
RF_MAX_BINS = 2048
LABEL = "DepDelay15Min"
CATEGORICAL_FEATURES = ["UniqueCarrier", "Origin", "Dest"]

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.mllib.tree import RandomForest
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from time import *

# Creates Spark Session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(APP_NAME).master(SPARK_URL).getOrCreate()

# Reads in CSV file as DataFrame
# header: The first line of files are used to name columns and are not included in data. All types are assumed to be string.
# inferSchema: Automatically infer column types. It requires one extra pass over the data.
df = spark.read.options(header = "true", inferschema = "true").csv(CSV_PATH)

# Transforms all strings into indexed numbers
indexers = [StringIndexer(inputCol=column, outputCol=column+"_index").fit(df) for column in CATEGORICAL_FEATURES]
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexers)
df = pipeline.fit(df).transform(df)

# Removes old string columns
df = df.drop(*CATEGORICAL_FEATURES)

# Moves the label to the last column
df = StringIndexer(inputCol=LABEL, outputCol=LABEL+"_label").fit(df).transform(df)
df = df.drop(LABEL)

# Converts the DataFrame into a LabeledPoint Dataset with the last column being the label and the rest the features.
transformed_df = df.rdd.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row[-1], Vectors.dense(row[0:-1])))

# Splits the dataset into a training and testing set according to the defined ratio using the defined random seed.
splits = [TRAINING_DATA_RATIO, 1.0 - TRAINING_DATA_RATIO]
training_data, test_data = transformed_df.randomSplit(splits, RANDOM_SEED)

print("Number of training set rows: %d" % training_data.count())
print("Number of test set rows: %d" % test_data.count())

# Run algorithm and measure runtime
start_time = time()

model = RandomForest.trainClassifier(training_data, numClasses=2, categoricalFeaturesInfo={}, numTrees=RF_NUM_TREES, featureSubsetStrategy="auto", impurity="gini", maxDepth=RF_MAX_DEPTH, maxBins=RF_MAX_BINS, seed=RANDOM_SEED)

end_time = time()
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
print("Time to train model: %.3f seconds" % elapsed_time)

# Make predictions and compute accuracy
predictions = model.predict(test_data.map(lambda x: x.features))
labels_and_predictions = test_data.map(lambda x: x.label).zip(predictions)
acc = labels_and_predictions.filter(lambda x: x[0] == x[1]).count() / float(test_data.count())
print("Model accuracy: %.3f%%" % (acc * 100))
```

When executing the labels_and_predictions.filter() at the very end I get the following error message:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Unseen label: OR.  To handle unseen labels, set Param handleInvalid to keep.
        at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel$$anonfun$9.apply(StringIndexer.scala:260)
```

However, the label "OR" does not exist anywhere in the dataset, Only "ORD". I tried different datasets and it turned out that Spark keeps cutting off the last letter of the "Origin" row. I have not the slightest idea which part of the script could be responsible for this. Any ideas how I should proceed the investigation? Thanks and advance!

Comment: I’m not sure what’s causing this, but I’m suspecting it might be caused by the LabeledPoint Dataset transformation. Is there a reason you aren’t using Spark.ml library and the VectorAssembler?

Comment: @Erik No particular reason other than that I didn't know that it could be handled differently. What is the advantage of the VectorAssembler over a LabeledPoint transformation? And what do you mean by not using Spark.ml? I thought this is exactly what I am doing (or at least that pyspark.ml is calling spark.ml underneath)? Could you point me to an example which uses the VectorAssembler? Thanks!

Comment: it looks like you're using pyspark.mllib and not pyspark.ml. MLLib is the RDD based ML library, while ML is the Dataframe based ML library. Instead of trying to get everything into a LabeledPoint transformation and dropping all of the intermediate columns, you can use pyspark.ml and then use DataFrames. The advantage is that you don't have to use RDDs (which are usually slower than Dataframes and more prone to errors.) You can also use them in your Pipeline - which will make scoring much easier. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorassembler

Comment: @Erik Thanks a lot for your advice! I still don't understand why my solution wasn't working but after porting it to the ML library it works just fine. I will post my new script here as well.

Answer (score 0):

As Erik pointed out I was using the outdated MLLib instead of the ML library. I still do not understand why the original script was not working but after porting it to ML it does. Here is the new solution which is inspired by this example: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#random-forest-classifier

```
CSV_PATH = "data/mllib/2004_10000_small.csv"
APP_NAME = "Random Forest Example"
SPARK_URL = "local[*]"
RANDOM_SEED = 13579
TRAININGDATA_RATIO = 0.7
VI_MAX_CATEGORIES = 4
RF_NUM_TREES = 10
RF_MAX_DEPTH = 30
RF_MAX_BINS = 2048
LABEL = "DepDelay15Min"
CATEGORICAL_FEATURES = ["UniqueCarrier", "Origin", "Dest"]

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.feature import IndexToString, StringIndexer, VectorAssembler, VectorIndexer
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from time import *

# Creates Spark Session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(APP_NAME).master(SPARK_URL).getOrCreate()

# Reads in CSV file as DataFrame
# header: The first line of files are used to name columns and are not included in data. All types are assumed to be string.
# inferSchema: Automatically infer column types. It requires one extra pass over the data.
data = spark.read.options(header = "true", inferschema = "true").csv(CSV_PATH)

# Transforms all string features into indexed numbers
indexers = [StringIndexer(inputCol=column, outputCol=column+"_index").fit(data) for column in CATEGORICAL_FEATURES]
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexers)
data = pipeline.fit(data).transform(data)

# Removes old string columns
data = data.drop(*CATEGORICAL_FEATURES)

# Indexes the label and moves it to the last column
data = StringIndexer(inputCol=LABEL, outputCol="label").fit(data).transform(data)
data = data.drop(LABEL)

# Assembles all feature columns and moves them to the last column
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=data.columns[0:-1], outputCol="features")
data = assembler.transform(data)

# Remove all columns but label and features
data = data.drop(*data.columns[0:-2])

# Splits the dataset into a training and testing set according to the defined ratio using the defined random seed.
splits = [TRAININGDATA_RATIO, 1.0 - TRAININGDATA_RATIO]
trainingData, testData = data.randomSplit(splits, RANDOM_SEED)

print("Number of training set rows: %d" % trainingData.count())
print("Number of test set rows: %d" % testData.count())

# Index labels, adding metadata to the label column.
# Fit on whole dataset to include all labels in index.
labelIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="label", outputCol="indexedLabel").fit(data)

# Automatically identify categorical features, and index them.
# Set maxCategories so features with > VI_MAX_CATEGORIES distinct values are treated as continuous.
featureIndexer = VectorIndexer(inputCol="features", outputCol="indexedataeatures", maxCategories=VI_MAX_CATEGORIES).fit(data)

# Train a RandomForest model.
randomForest = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol="indexedLabel", featuresCol="indexedataeatures", numTrees=RF_NUM_TREES, maxBins=RF_MAX_BINS)

# Convert indexed labels back to original labels.
labelConverter = IndexToString(inputCol="prediction", outputCol="predictedLabel", labels=labelIndexer.labels)

# Chain indexers and forest in a Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[labelIndexer, featureIndexer, randomForest, labelConverter])

# Train model.  This also runs the indexers. Measures the execution time as well.
start_time = time()
model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)
end_time = time()

# Make predictions.
predictions = model.transform(testData)

# Select example rows to display.
predictions.select("predictedLabel", "label", "features").show(5)

# Select (prediction, true label) and compute test error
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol="indexedLabel", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="accuracy")
accuracy = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
print("Test Error = %g" % (1.0 - accuracy))

rfModel = model.stages[2]
print(rfModel)  # summary only
```